# webdriver not able to click pop up window with certificate error page

Tags: c#, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using webdriver 2.40.0 (installed from nugget packages) and writing code in C# I am 
-   opening a link for my company website which generates a certificate error page
-   clicking the override link element to allow me to continue to the site
-   clicking an enter button on that page which generates a pop up window that also had a certificate error page on top of it
My problem is when I try to select the pop up window a “noSuchWindowException” is thrown, code:

```
namespace webDriverDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string setURL = "xxxxx";

            IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"C:\Drivers");
            driver.Url = setURL;
            String loginPage = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;

            var securityLine = driver.FindElement(By.Id("overridelink"));
            if (!securityLine.Equals(null))
            {
                securityLine.Click();
            }

            var enterBtn = driver.FindElement(By.Id("EnterButton"));
            enterBtn.Click();

            //Select the pop up window


            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()");

            driver.SwitchTo().Window("xxxx");
```

I’ve tried:

`driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()")`

and

`String riskPage = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;`

and switching to that window, I’ve also tried

`driver.SwitchTo().Window();`

but I think the problem is that I can’t get to the window name of the certificate error page and cannot select and element on that page and try to save it as a separate handle. Really need help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have performed the action `enterBtn.Click();` that launches the popup window, you need to then switch context to the new window (using it's window handle, not  title) to be able to interact with it.

You can obtain the popup window's handle from the `driver.WindowHandles` list.

```
var riskPageHandle = driver.WindowHandles.FirstOrDefault(hwnd => hwnd != loginPageWindowHandle);

if(riskPageHandle ==null)
{
   //popup not found, log error or handle 
}
else
{
   //switch to the popup
   driver.SwitchTo().Window(riskPageHandle);
   Console.WriteLine("Popup window title is : " + driver.Title);

   //now accept the certificate error (your code, I haven't tried it)
   driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()");

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have used://Select the pop up window
            var riskPageHandle = driver.WindowHandles.FirstOrDefault(hwnd => hwnd != loginPage);

            driver.SwitchTo().Window(riskPageHandle);
            Console.WriteLine("Popup window title is : " + driver.Title);

            var overRde = driver.FindElement(By.Id("overridelink"));

            overRde.Click(); works a charm :) :)

Comment: could you explain var riskPageHandle = driver.WindowHandles.FirstOrDefault(hwnd => hwnd != loginPageWindowHandle);?? I'm not a developer im a tester, I understand that this is getting and saving the window handle of the pop up window but not sure how?

Comment: That is [LINQ FirstOrDefault method](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) syntax. It finds the first window handle in the list that is not your login page window handle(which you saved earlier). Since there are only 2 open windows, the second window handle belongs to the popup.